# Что я делаю ошибочно при попытке вывести значения из jsonb столбца в sql запросе?

Tags: json, postgresql

Дана таблица

| заголовок 1 | jsonb_data |
| --- | --- |
| id 1 | {"group003": {"f1-povod": ["1. Услуга1"], "First_call": ["Да"], "f1-gorod-main": ["Москва"]}, "group005": {"f1-result": ["8. Уточнил информацию"]}, "group007": {"f5-utochnenie": ["2. Как готовиться / что с собой брать / как добраться (уже записан ранее)"]}} |
| id 2 | {"forma001": {"res": ["Перенос записи"], "Status_pacienta": ["Клиент уже обслуживается"], "Zapros_v_filial": ["Петровские ворота"]}} |

нужно получить

| заголовок | ключ 1 (форма) | ключ 2 (f1-gorod-main) | ключ 3 (res) | ключ итд |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id 1 | forma001 | Москва | null | значение |
| id 2 | group003 | null | перенос записи | null |

делаю
следующий запрос:

```
select
    *
from
    mv_custom_form mcf
    cross join lateral
        jsonb_populate_record(null::mv_custom_form, jsondata)
where
    mcf.creationdate < '2023-09-23'
    and mcf.creationdate >= '2023-09-22'
```

Comment: `null::mv_custom_form` означает "достать из JSON данные, которые соответствуют структуре таблицы `mv_custom_form`. Если у тебя в таблице `mv_custom_form` нет колонок `f1-gorod-main`, `res` и прочее, то не стоит ожидать, что они магически появятся.

Comment: Вот тут список, что можно делать с JSON в Постгрисе https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE. Есть там что-нибудь, напоминающее твой сценарий ("динамически создать колонки из ключей второго уровня(!!!) в JSON"). Если нет, то тебе придётся задачу по другому решать. Например, создать rowtype, который обозначит интересующее тебя подмножество ключей.

Comment: Ещё вопрос - а что ты вообще собираешься делать с таким набором строк???

Comment: Александр, привет!
если кратко суть следующая: есть разные формы заполняемые сотрудниками.
в БД - несколько строк которые идентифицируют запись, и 1 строка с jsonb данными самой формы.
верховный вождь желает, чтобы это все валилось в одном отчете. соответственно надо вытащить этот json, и раскидать его по столбцам.
предполгаю, что возможно нужно организовать цикл с вытаскиванием пар ключей из каждой итерации..

Comment: Какого вида отчет? Если просто кол-во форм, полей, то тебе не надо это в колонки вытягивать. Проще представить данные в виде `form, field, value` и по этому виду уже гонять аналитику.

Answer (score 0):

Для отчёта не надо тащить всё в колонки, можно (и нужно) обойтись строками

```sql
with my_custom_form as (
  select 1 as id, '{"group003": {"f1-povod": ["1. Услуга1"], "First_call": ["Да"], "f1-gorod-main": ["Москва"]}, "group005": {"f1-result": ["8. Уточнил информацию"]}, "group007": {"f5-utochnenie": ["2. Как готовиться / что с собой брать / как добраться (уже записан ранее)"]}}'::jsonb as jsonb_data
  union select 2, '{"forma001": {"res": ["Перенос записи"], "Status_pacienta": ["Клиент уже обслуживается"], "Zapros_v_filial": ["Петровские ворота"]}}'
), forms as (
  select id, form.* 
  from my_custom_form 
  cross join jsonb_each_text(jsonb_data) as form
), fields as (
  select id, forms.key as form, field.* 
  from forms 
  cross join json_each_text(forms.value::json) as field
)
select * from fields
```

выводит

| id | form | key | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | group003 | f1-povod | ["1. Услуга1"] |
| 1 | group003 | First_call | ["Да"] |
| 1 | group003 | f1-gorod-main | ["Москва"] |
| 1 | group005 | f1-result | ["8. Уточнил информацию"] |
| 1 | group007 | f5-utochnenie | ["2. Как готовиться / что с собой брать / как добраться (уже записан ранее)"] |
| 2 | forma001 | res | ["Перенос записи"] |
| 2 | forma001 | Status_pacienta | ["Клиент уже обслуживается"] |
| 2 | forma001 | Zapros_v_filial | ["Петровские ворота"] |

И по этому набору уже можно строить отчёты (например, `group by form, field`)

Comment: формально логика понятна. но для агрегации кмк проще если столбцы и будут ключами - как в теме поста.
т.к. мало того, что эти значения нужно получить - их еще нужно обработать.

я вижу этот как создание друх таблиц одна с периодами времени, а вторая как раз с полученными значениями.

т.е. итоговый результат - кол-во форм с таким то ответом. в период времени (допустим сутки)

спасибо за вашу мысль